# sshd crashing after reboot

Tags: 16.04, ssh

This is the log from syslog relevant to the crashes -

```
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us sshd[1437]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 20: Bad configuration option: KexDHMin
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us sshd[1437]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is someone familiar with this - **"Bad configuration option: KexDHMin"**?

**Edit**:
Current line 20 of sshd_config file -

```
ServerKeyBits 1024
```

**This might not be the line 20 of sshd_config file when the issue was present.

Comment: My sshd_config does not have that line. If you comment it out does it work?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/908548/edit) and add the contents of line 20 of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to your question. It should start with `KexDHMin`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex This is a cloud instance. Right now sshd is working and line 20 of sshd_config is -  ServerKeyBits 1024. I don't have the config file when sshd was not working.

Comment: @nullmeta, right now I don't see any lines with KexDHMin in sshd_config file in that VM. This is a cloud instance. When the file was corrupted I did not have access.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a crash. It just fails to start because of wrong configuration option:

```
Apr 17 12:34:14 hn0-hdi-us sshd[1437]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 20: Bad configuration option: KexDHMin
```

The option `ServerKeyBits` is also deprecated in current OpenSSH. I don't think this option is there shipped by default Ubuntu so just remove it. It is not useful for anything (unless you use SSH-1 protocol for some reason, but in that case you are already screwed).